# pickle.load() a dictionary with duplicate keys and reduce

Tags: python, python-2.7

For reasons concerning `MemoryError`, I am appending a series of dictionaries to a file like `pickle.dump(mydict, open(filename, "a"))`. The entirety of the dictionary, as far as I can tell, can't be constructed in my laptop's memory. **As a result** I have identical keys in the same pickled file. The file is essentially a hash table of doublets and strings. The data looks like:

```
{
    'abc': [list of strings1],
    'efg': [list of strings2],
    'abc': [list of strings3]
}
```

- *Main Question:* When I use `pickle.load(open(filename, "r"))` is there a way to join the duplicate dictionary keys?
- *Question 2:* Does it matter that there are duplicates? Will calling the duplicate key give me **all** applicable results?

For example:

```
mydict = pickle.load(open(filename, "r"))
mydict['abc'] = <<sum of all lists with this key>>
```

One solution I've considered, but I'm not clear on from a Python-knowledge standpoint:

```
x = mydict['abc']
if type(x[0]) is list:
    reduce(lambda a, b: a.extend(b), x)
<<do processing on list items>>
```

---

**Edit 1:** Here's the flow of data, roughly speaking.

1. *Daily:* update `table_ownership` with 100-500 new records. Each record contains 1 or 2 strings (names of people).
2. Create a new hash table of 3-letter groups, tied to the strings that contain the doublet. The key is the doublet, the value is a list of strings (actually a tuple containing the string and the primary key for the `table_ownership` record.
3. *Hourly:* update `table_people` with 10-40 new names to match.
4. Use the hash table to pull the most likely matches PRIOR to running fuzzy matching. We get the doublets from `myString` and strings like `potential_matches.append(hashTable[doublet]) for doublet in get_doublets(myString)`
5. Sort by shared doublet count.
6. Apply fuzzy matching to top 5000 `potential_matches`, storing results of high quality in `table_fuzzymatches`

So this works very well, and it's 10-100 times faster than fuzzymatching straight away. With only 200k records, I can make the hash table in memory and `pickle.dump()` but with the full 1.65M records I can't.

---

**Edit 2:** I'm looking into 2 things:

- x64 Python
- 'collections.defaultdict'

I'll report back.

Comment: Unpickeling that will probably drop one of the values or cause an error. That's not a legal dictionary, so I doubt it has ways of dealing with it.

Comment: I suspect you've misunderstood the structure of the data you're dumping into this file.

Comment: I believe JSON would be better suited to this, if you only keep dicts and lists.

Comment: None of this is going to help with your memory issues if you're planning to just load all the data into memory at the end anyway.

Comment: @user2357112 - This is possible, but I don't think so. Why do you think so?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - I am pulling 1.65M records (each containing 1 or 2 strings of length 20-ish. The hash table (aka pickled data in a file) is stored for fuzzy matching against ~100 records daily. I'm not sure JSON is the way to go..

Comment: @PANDAStack: If you're dumping multiple dicts to the same file, that isn't going to result in one pickle of a dict with duplicate keys. That's going to result in multiple pickles.

Comment: @user2357112 - then I am in a... ahem... pickle. Please see my edit on the flow of the whole shebang. I really don't know what to do, since it FEELS like I should be able to hold this `doublet:list` dict in memory but I can't seem to create it there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers:

- 32bit Python has a 2GB memory limit. x64 fixed my problem right away.

But what if I hadn't had 64bit Python available?

- Chunk the input.

When I used a 10**5 chunk size and wrote to a dictionary piecemeal, it worked out.

For timing, my chunking process took 2000 seconds. 64bit Python sped it up to 380 seconds.